# Action of a projection on a sequence of pairwise orthogonal subspaces.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

Let us consider a sequence of finite-dimensional subspaces $\{H_n\}$ with $dim H_n=dim H_m$  and $H_n\perp H_m$ ($m\neq n$) in the Hilbert space $H$. Does there exist any projection $P$ satisfying in the following relations: 
$$0\neq \overline{P(H_n)}=\overline{P(H_m)}=\overline{P(\cup_{j\geq1} H_j)}$$
where $m\neq n$.

Comment: Ali, I need you to unaccept my answer,  so that I can delete it.

Answer (score 1):

*My answer was wrong. The mistake that invalidates the whole argument happened between $(5) $ and $(6)$, where 
$$
\lambda_{jk}P_{jj}=\lambda_{jk}\lambda_{kj}P_{kk}
$$
should have been
$$
\lambda_{jk}P_{jj}=\lambda_{jk}\lambda_{kj}^2P_{kk},
$$ which gives no new information whatsoever.*

Comment: You use in your problem multiple times that $P$ is self-adjoint. This is not required in general as some definitions of "projection" require it and some do not.

Comment: I have never seen any book nor paper in operator algebras that uses the word "projection" to describe an idempotent.

Comment: Vilmos Komornik's Lectures on Functional Analysis and the Lebesgue Integral and Joseph Muscat's Functional Analysis both use projection to mean idempotent and orthogonal projection to mean also self-adjoint.

Carlos S. Kubrusly's Spectral Theory of Operators on Hilbert Spaces seems to do the same, but some of the terminology seemed a little muddied.

Konrad Schmüdgen's Unbounded Self-adjoint Operators on Hilbert Space is clear about the matter: "By a projection we mean an orthogonal projection."

It seems that the more generality aimed at, a projection is just idempotent.

Comment: I said "Operator Algebras", which is the most specific tag in this question, and not "Functional Analysis".

Comment: "Spectral Theory of Operators on Hilbert Spaces" seems like operator theory

Comment: Yes. But I said "Operator Algebras". Still many  Operator Theory books use "projection" meaning "selfadjoint idempotent": Some books in Operator Theory:
\begin{align}
&\text{Arveson W.,   A Short Course on Spectral Theory}\\
&\text{Conway,  A Course in Operator Theory }\\
&\text{Conway,   A Course in Functional analysis}\\
&\text{Farenick,  Functional Analysis}\\
\end{align}
And in Operator Algebras, as I said, it is the standard. For instance (continued)

Comment: \begin{align}
&\text{Arveson W. An invitation to C-algebras}\\
&\text{BingRen, Operator Algebras}\\
&\text{Blackadar, Operator Algebras}\\
&\text{Brown -- Ozawa, C$^*$-Algebras and Finite-Dimensional Approximations} \\
&\text{Davidson K.R., C-star-algebras by example }\\
&\text{de la Harpe P., Jones V.,  An introduction to C-star algebras}\\
&\text{Dixmier, C$^*$-algebras}\\
&\text{Kadison R.V., Ringrose J.R.,  Fundamentals of the theory of operator algebras}\\
&\text{Murphy,  C$^*$-algebras and operator theory }\\
&\text{Sakai S.,  C$^*$-algebras and W-star-algebras }\\
\end{align}

Comment: \begin{align}
&\text{Stratila and Zsido,  Lectures_on_von Neumann Algebras}\\
&\text{Takesaki M.,  Theory of operator algebras I}\\
&\text{Thomsen, Classification-C-Star-Algebras}\\
&\text{Wegge-Olsen N.E.,  K-theory and C-star-algebras.. A friendly approach }
\end{align}

Comment: This is also Stack exchange and so it is conceivable that the intended question was asking about any sort of projection.

But strictly speaking, yes, it seems that in general operator theory (where the operators are able to be viewed as acting on Hilbert spaces, I guess) a projection is self-adjoint, just as often projections on Hilbert spaces are assumed to be self-adjoint, since those are the ones people are mainly interested in, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

If $P$ is assumed to be self-adjoint (and hence the term "orthogonal projection" is redundant.) then Martin Argerami has given an answer to this.

Either way, my response below is that such a $P$ does exist in any case.

For each $H_j$, pick a unit vector $e_j \in H_j$. Since the $H_j$ are orthogonal, this means that $\{e_j\}$ is an orthonormal set. Let $P$ be the orthogonal projection onto the vector $v = \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{1}{j^2}e_j$, i.e. for each $w \in H$, $P(w) = \langle w, v\rangle \frac{v}{\|v\|}$. Note that $v \neq 0$ since the $e_j$ are orthogonal so $\|v\|^2 = \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{1}{j^4} > 0$, by the (infinite) Pythagorean theorem.

We then see that $P(H_j) = \operatorname{span}(v)$ since $e_j \in H_j$ and $P(e_j) = \frac{1}{j^2}v$. It then follows that $P(H_j)$ is a one dimensional subspace and hence closed so $\overline{P(H_j)} = P(H_j) = \operatorname{im} P$, the image of $P$. Note that the image of $P$ is closed. We then see that $$P\left(\bigcup_{j \geq 1} H_j\right) = \bigcup_{j \geq 1} P(H_j) = \bigcup_{j \geq 1} \operatorname{im} P = \operatorname{im} P$$ and so $P$ satisfies all the required properties.

Comment: Nice. You need $v $ to be a unit vector to make $P $ an orthogonal projection; you can simply use $2^{-j/2} $ instead of $1/j^2$. Now when I have some time I need to find what's wrong with my argument.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried anything?

Try the simple case $H = \mathbb{C}^n$ and $H_i = \{(0,0, \dots, 0, z, 0, \dots) : z \in \mathbb{C}\}$ is the span of the $i$th standard basis vector. (Try $n = 2$ and $n = 3$.)

Can you find a projection with the above properties in this case? If not, then why not?

Can you extend this to the general case?

Comment: -1: I fail to see how this contributes at all to answer the case where $H$ is inifinite-dimensional, which is what the OP is asking.

Comment: The OP did not contribute anything to the problem and so I thought that I would try to get the ball rolling. Moreover, although the question is specifically framed for a separable Hilbert space, the question applies equally well to any Hilbert space with any collection of orthogonal subspaces so thinking about this can help get some familiarity with the problem (it would be the first thing I would do). Moreover, any solution to the OP's problem could be projected onto a solution for the finite dimensional problem that I suggest.

Comment: In particular, it makes the OP consider what it would look like for the image of a projection applied to two orthogonal spaces to be equal would look like.

Comment: The OP is aware of [what happens in the finite-dimensional case](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2894045/action-of-a-projection-on-a-pairwise-orthogonal-projections). And I'm curious about what you mean by "projected onto a solution for the finite-dimensional problem"; how exactly do you "project" an infinite-dimensional projection onto a finite-dimensional one?

Comment: First, the OP might not have been aware of that. (Again, the OP showed no sign that any thought had been put into the problem beyond its statement.) Second, if such a $P$ exists in the problem and we take $H_1, \dots, H_n$ to be finitely many of the problem, then we can form the projection onto a subspace generated by these $H_i$ and $P(H_i)$. Then $P$ is a projection on this finite dim subspace and satisfies the properties. And even if there was no descent onto fin. dim., thinking about finite dim helps one understand the infinite dim problem, e.g. any limiting condition as dim increases.

Comment: It's a bold claim that the OP is not aware to an answer to his own question, that he accepted yesterday. As for "projecting down", I would still like to see how you use that to start with the solution $\mathbb C^3$ and get the solution in $\mathbb C^2$.

Comment: First, you claimed that the OP knew something. I claimed that it was not clear and "The OP might not have been aware of that", because no effort was shown by the OP in solving the problem and many times people on the forum post questions that have already been answered, hence the "duplicate" mark added to many posts. Your claim that I am making bold claims and supporting your claim with interaction with OP by posting solutions, does not invalidate my claim, because before OP interacted with you, you also knew nothing of OP's knowledge. I was giving OP starting-suggestions, what I would do.

Comment: Second, my suggestion about going from infin dim to fin dim does not apply to $d=3$ to $d=2$ necessarily in all cases. I still believe that if there existed a $P$ for infinite dim and each $H_i$ are fin dim, then my construction gives a $P$ for fin dim. If $H_i$ have dim $p | d$ then taking $P$ of $\mathbb{C}^d$ restricted to $H_1, \dots, H_k, P(H_1)$ gives a solution for $P$ for dim $d_k$ and $pk \leq d_k \leq (p+1)k$, depending on the intersection of the image of $P$ with the $H_i, i = 1, \dots, k$.

Comment: Note the image of $P$ is all the is required since first $P(\left(\bigcup_i H_i\right)) = \overline{P\left(\bigcup_i H_i\right)} = \overline{P(H_j)} = P(H_j)$ since $P(H_j)$ are $1$ or $0$ dim subspaces and hence closed and then $P\left(\bigcup_i H_i\right) = \bigcup_i P(H_i) = \bigcup P(H_j) = P(H_j)$. Now, since the span of $P(H_i)$ is the image of $P$, we see that for each $J$, $P(H_j)$ is the image of $P$ and then we see that $P$ is a rank $p$ projection.

Comment: So, in going from $d=3$ to $d=2$, suppose that we have $H_1, H_2$ in $\mathbb{C}^2$. Then we identify this as a subspace of $\mathbb{C}^3$ via $\iota: \mathbb{C}^2 \hookrightarrow \mathbb{C}^3$ and then $H_3$ is the orthogonal complement and then get a projection $P$ from the $d=3$ solution. if $Q: \mathbb{C}^3 \to \mathbb{C}^2$ is an othogonal projection that fixes each $H_1, H_2$ and annihilates $H_3$, we see that $Q\circ P \circ \iota$ satisfies the conditions of the problem because the only condition, as shown before, for a solution is that $P(H_j)$ is independent of $j$.

Comment: Correction: (AT MOST) rank $p$ projection.

Comment: And why would $QP\iota$ be a projection?

Comment: First, it is nonzero, because the kernel of $Q$ is $H_3.$ Then calculating the matrix gives that its matrix is the upper-right corner submatrix. So it is self-adjoint since $P$ is. ... but is not necessarily a projection, because of an example of finite dim projections.
Ok, so I suppose that maybe projecting down does not work. However, I still believe that restricting $P$ to the span of $H_1, \dots, H_k, P(H_1)$ does work though, but the $H_k$'s do not span. :(

However, my working out of the fin dim case helped me find the inf dim case, which is what I was saying in my original answer.

Comment: Thanks for working with me.
Note: I am not a "new user". I just lost my password and had to sign up again.